# Identify the original variable used to calculate the dummies

Tags: r, categorical-data

I have a data frame where many quantitative variables have been recoded as dummy variables.

Here is a reproductible example using R:

```
age <- round(runif(100, 15, 40), 0)

as.dummy <- function(variable, min, max){
  sapply(variable, function(x) 
    if((!is.null(min) && x> min | is.null(min)) & ((!is.null(max) && x <= max) | is.null(max) ) )
      1
    else
      0
  )
}

age2 <- as.dummy(age, NULL, 20)
age3 <- as.dummy(age, 20, 25)
age4 <- as.dummy(age, 25, 30)
age5 <- as.dummy(age, 30, NULL)
tab <- data.frame(age, age2, age3, age4, age5)
```

Is there a way to detect that age2...5 are constructed from the variable age? 
I would like to be able to detect those dummy variables and remove them of the data frame.

Here I give the example of variables coded 0/1 but it can be also coded as "yes/no", or anything else.

Comment: You will appreciate reading the help page for the `cut` function: it will save you work in the future.  Use it in conjunction with `model.matrix`.

Comment: I don't understand why this was closed, and I would appreciate someone explaining the reasoning to me in chat: https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/43453415#43453415 Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

This answer suggests there is value in a graphical exploration of relationships among the variables and illustrates one useful way.  It then provides a simple solution that *rapidly and automatically* identifies all possible variables that might be represented by a given categorical variable.

---

You can explore graphically by drawing a scatterplot matrix of the age categories and all numerical variables in the data frame.  If there are many variables, summarize each by age and check that they fall into non-overlapping intervals.

Here are some sample data for illustration.  The grouping variable is `V1`, but let's pretend we don't know that.

```
#
# Create data for testing.
#
n.obs <- 100
n.vars <- 4
X <- as.data.frame(matrix(round(runif(n.obs*n.vars, 15, 40), 0), n.obs))
#
# Create the dummary variable.
#
cutpoints <- c(-Inf, 20, 25, 30, Inf)
Age <- data.frame(group=cut(X$V1, cutpoints))
```

This scatterplot matrix makes it obvious that variable `V1` corresponds to the age groups in `group`, because it is the only variable that is clearly partitioned by a scatterplot in the `group` row or column:

```
colors <- rainbow(length(cutpoints), alpha=0.6)
names(colors) <- unique(Age$group)
pairs(cbind(X, Age), pch=21, bg=colors[Age$group])
```

[image: Scatterplot matrix]

I recommend using this approach in any event because if *no* variables are found to match the `age` variable (as shown below), with this plot you may quickly identify any variables that *almost* match it.  This can be useful for forensic activities such as identifying inconsistencies in a data table.

An `R` implementation of a summary by age uses `tapply` to break data into groups by age and `by` to compute their ranges.  If these are non-overlapping (as ordered by `by`), you have a candidate for a correspondence with age.

```
#
# Identify all columns of X that might match Age.
# The result is a logical vector indicating which fields of X match.
#
candidates <- sapply(names(X), function(f) {
  groups <- tapply(X[[f]], Age)
  boundaries <- unlist(by(X[f], groups, range))
  identical(order(boundaries), 1:length(boundaries))
})

message(paste0("Possible variables are (", paste(names(X)[candidates],
                collapse=","), ")."))
```

The output is

> Possible variables are (V1).

Although this example used data in the form usually stored in a database--namely, as a categorical variable--it will work without change when `Age` is a data frame in the format given in the question: unique rows of `Age` are used for grouping.

Answer (score 3):

If you can perfectly reconstruct the dummies from a candidate predictor, then the dummies and the predictor carry the same information. If the dummies encode intervals of the predictor (the most common way of discretizing continuous predictors, which is a bad idea, as discussed often here on CV, but that's not the focus), then you should be able to model the dummies perfectly with a [multinomial logistic regression](https://stats.idre.ucla.edu/r/dae/multinomial-logistic-regression/) on the predictor:

```
library(nnet)
# encode the dummies into a single factor variable:
tab$age.level <- as.factor(apply(tab[,-1],1,function(xx)min(which(xx==1))))
model <- multinom(age.level~age,tab)
predict(model)
table(predict(model),tab$age.level)

     1  2  3  4
  1 12  0  0  0
  2  0 22  0  0
  3  0  0 25  0
  4  0  0  0 41
```

We get a perfect confusion matrix. This would be convincing enough for me.

Answer (score 0):

To detect that age2...5 are constructed from the same variable, you can check if the sum of those dummy variables equals 1 :

```
all(age2+age3+age4+age5==1)
```

But I don't know if there is a way to check if they come specifically from the variable age, it could be any other variable in the dataframe.

Comment: I believe the situation isn't quite as bad as that.  When a dummy $I$ is constructed from a variable $X$, it is as a *function* of $X$.  By definition that means it's impossible for the value of $I$ to differ for observations where the value of $X$ is the same.  This simple relation can be used effectively to *rule out* any other variables in the data frame that violate it. If you also know (or assume) $I$ corresponds to *intervals* of $X$, this leads to an even better check that very well might rule out all other variables except age.

Comment: This works because there is no intercept here. In the more common case where there is an intercept, we would need to check whether the sum is 1 *or 0*: `all(age2+age3+age4+age5 %in% c(0,1))`